# jQuery onClick for expanding text content on the right for a portfolio page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to achieve the same effect as it is on hover on my first fiddle,
I would like to use jquery click/toggle to expand the content instead of seeing it on hover

I am trying the basic addClass with jquery/css but somehow it's breaking off and cannot figure it out how to work properly

Would appreciate any help or advice on the following, thanks a lot in advance,

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqxAR/31/) i created with the jquery I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gamewrapper").click(function(){
    $(".gamewrapper").addClass("expand");
  });
});
```

I've played around and manage to do it with the toggleClass option, but still is showing only the second content on both captures, here is the newest code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqxAR/38/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gamewrapper").click(function(){
    $(".game-name").toggleClass("black");
    $(".gamewrapper").toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to the actual clicked element. So use `this` instead of `.gamewrapper` again ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YqxAR/39/)). Also add the context `this` to the `.game-name` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gamewrapper").click(function(){
    $(".game-name", this).toggleClass("black");
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any chance to animate the actual expansion, I tried with ("expand", 1000) but it doesn't look right? Thanks a lot in advance!